# Access iphone device login mail in my application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am new one Iphone developer

How to access device login mail inbox in my application. It is possible or not.

please help me.

Comment: what u want ?? plz Clear... u want login screen ??

Comment: No.. I need a inbox mail..

Answer (score 0):

No. Apple doesn't provide an API for that.

However, you're free to ask the user for their mail server settings and then talk directly to an IMAP server, downloading the mail/attachments yourself.

If you have presets for popular email providers (MobileMe, Gmail, Yahoo, etc.) this won't have to be too difficult for most users to deal with.